# php array complex search

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
[0] =>
   ['lang'] => 'DE',
   ['message'] => 'some text'
[1] =>
   ['lang'] => 'EN',
   ['message'] => 'some text'
[2] =>
   ['lang'] => 'NZ',
   ['message'] => 'some text'
[3] =>
   ['lang'] => 'CH',
   ['message'] => 'some text'
```

and clause like this if `$lang = 'NZ'` not found then find and return message for `$default_lang = 'DE'`, else return message for `'NZ'`

my realization:

```
foreach($res_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($res_arr[$key]['lang'] == $lang) {
        return $res_arr[$key]['message'];
    }
}

foreach($res_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($res_arr[$key]['lang'] == $default_lang) {
        return $res_arr[$key]['message'];
    }
}
```

is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Quick idea: If possible, create the array to have the language codes as keys. Then you can check if there is an entry for the specific language in your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$lang = ''; // lang param
$default_lang = 'DE';
$languages = array(
  'DE' => 'some text',
  'EN' => 'some text',
  'NZ' => 'some text',
  'CH' => 'some text'
);

if ( !isset($languages[$lang]) ) {
  $lang = $default_lang;
}
$message = $languages[$lang];
```

**Edit**

Way to transform your array into my `$languages` array:

```
$languages  = array();
$your_array = array( /* your data */ );

foreach ( $your_array as $val ) {
  $languages[ $val['lang'] ] = $val['message'];
}
```

Comment: this is the fastest method I know this, but firstly I somehow should transform my array into yours and I dunno how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a doubtful whether array_search will work here i.e. on multi-dimenstional array. Anyways, here is my solution:

```
$default_lang_msg = '';
foreach($res_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($res_arr[$key]['lang'] == $lang) {
        return $res_arr[$key]['message'];
    }
    else if ($res_arr[$key]['lang'] == $default_lang) {
        $default_lang_msg = $res_arr[$key]['message'];
    }    
}

return $default_lang_msg;
```

btw array with language code as keys is the way to go if you can afford to change the same.